# Using generalized method of moments (GMM) to calculate logistic regression parameter

Tags: logistic, generalized-moments

I want to calculate coefficients to a regression that is very similar to logistic regression (Actually logistic regression with another coefficient:
$$ \frac{A}{1 + e^{- (b_0 + b_1  x_1 + b_2  x_2 + \ldots)}},$$
when $A$ could be given).
I thought of using GMM to calculate the coefficients, but I'm not sure what are the moment conditions I should use.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "$A$ could be given", do you mean it is specified by the user or it is estimated by the model?

Comment: either way. I can put it as an input (e.g.A = 0.25) or be one of the coefficients to be found

Comment: Does it vary from subject to subject (i.e. is it data) or is it a fixed constant across all observations?

Comment: fixed on all observations (like b0, b1, ...)

Comment: In the specific case where A=1 we get regular logistic regression

Comment: Why not use maximum likelihood instead of GMM?

Comment: Are you sure your model is correct? Your probabilities are not scaled from $0$ to $1$ if $A \neq 1$.

Comment: We also trying to use Maximum likelihood, but would like to compare the results with GMM

Comment: Yes, we're looking for something that has probability between 0-0.25 and not between 0-1.

Comment: @user5497, the MLE is a more efficient estimator than the GMM estimator. It seems you'd only consider using the GMM estimator if calculating the MLE was intractable for some reason (which it isn't in this case).

Comment: @Macro, maximum likelihood requires assuming a distribution while GMM does not. ML is more efficient if the distributional assumption happens to be  correct but not otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming $A\leq 1$, this model has Bernoulli response variable $Y_i$ with

$$
Pr(Y_i = 1) = \frac{A}{1+e^{-X_i'b}},
$$

where $b$ (and possibly $A$, depending on whether it is treated as a constant or a parameter) are the fitted coefficients and $X_i$ is the data for observation $i$. I assume the intercept term is handled by adding a variable with constant value 1 to the data matrix.

The moment conditions are:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(Y_i-\frac{A}{1+e^{-X_i'b}}\bigg)X_i\bigg] &= 0.
\end{align*}

We replace this with the sample counterpart of the condition, assuming $N$ observations:

$$
m = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \bigg[\bigg(Y_i-\frac{A}{1+e^{-X_i'b}}\bigg)X_i\bigg] = 0
$$

This is practically solved by minimizing $m'm$ across all possible coefficient values $b$ (below we will use the [Nelder-Mead simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) to perform this optimization).

Borrowing from [an excellent R-bloggers tutorial on the topic](http://www.r-bloggers.com/nonlinear-gmm-with-r-example-with-a-logistic-regression/), it is pretty straightforward to implement this in R with the gmm package. As an example, let's work with the iris dataset, predicting if an iris is versicolor based on its sepal length and width and petal length and width. I'll assume $A$ is constant and equal to 1 in this case:

```r
dat <- as.matrix(cbind(data.frame(IsVersicolor = as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor"), Intercept=1), iris[,1:4]))
head(dat)
#      IsVersicolor Intercept Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# [1,]            0         1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
# [2,]            0         1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
# [3,]            0         1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
# [4,]            0         1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
# [5,]            0         1          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
# [6,]            0         1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Here are the coefficients fitted using logistic regression:

```r
summary(glm(IsVersicolor~., data=as.data.frame(dat[,-2]), family="binomial"))
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)    7.3785     2.4993   2.952 0.003155 ** 
# Sepal.Length  -0.2454     0.6496  -0.378 0.705634    
# Sepal.Width   -2.7966     0.7835  -3.569 0.000358 ***
# Petal.Length   1.3136     0.6838   1.921 0.054713 .  
# Petal.Width   -2.7783     1.1731  -2.368 0.017868 *
```

The main piece we need to use gmm is a function that returns the moment conditions, namely rows $(Y_i-\frac{A}{1+e^{-X_i'b}})X_i$ for each observation $i$:

```r
moments <- function(b, X) {
  A <- 1
  as.vector(X[,1] - A / (1 + exp(-(X[,-1] %*% cbind(b))))) * X[,-1]
}
```

We can now numerically fit coefficients $b$, using the linear regression coefficients as a convenient initial point (as suggested in the tutorial linked above):

```r
init.coef <- lm(IsVersicolor~., data=as.data.frame(dat[,-2]))$coefficients
library(gmm)
fitted <- gmm(moments, x = dat, t0 = init.coef, type = "iterative", crit = 1e-19,
              wmatrix = "optimal", method = "Nelder-Mead",
              control = list(reltol = 1e-19, maxit = 20000))
fitted
#  (Intercept)  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
#      7.37849      -0.24536      -2.79657       1.31364      -2.77834  
# 
# Convergence code =  0
```

The convergence code of 0 indicates the procedure converged, and the parameters are identical to those returned by logistic regression.

A quick look at the gmm package source (functions `momentEstim.baseGmm.iterative` and `gmm:::.obj1` for the parameters provided) shows that the gmm package is minimizing $m'm$ as indicated above. The following equivalent code calls the R `optim` function directly, performing the same optimization we achieved above with the call to `gmm`:

```r
gmm.objective <- function(theta, x, momentFun) {
  avg.moment <- colMeans(momentFun(theta, x))
  sum(avg.moment^2)
}
optim(init.coef, gmm.objective, x=dat, momentFun=moments,
      control = list(reltol = 1e-19, maxit = 20000))$par
#  (Intercept) Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#    7.3784866   -0.2453567   -2.7965681    1.3136433   -2.7783439
```

Comment: How did you arrive at that moment condition? @josliber

Comment: Is it a Taylor expansion?

Comment: @user0 I'm not sure I can provide a comprehensive answer of the derivation; I just followed the well-known moment condition for logistic regression here. Perhaps you could ask a new question to get a canonical answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I looked a bit, and I think it is actually interestingly the expectation of the derivative of the log likelihood (derivation: https://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf). I guess scores/derivatives of the likelihood need to be zero to maximize the likelihood, so this makes sense sort of. I wonder though how to find these moment conditions for functions that are not easily differentiable,

Answer (score 1):

One intuition for the moment conditions:

$E\left[ \left(Y_i - \frac{1}{1+e^{-X_i' \beta} }\right)X_i \right]$

Is that you want your prediction errors to be mean zero and uncorrelated with the independent variables.

Once you think of $\epsilon_i = Y_i- \frac{1} {1+e^{-X_i'\beta}}$ as an error term, then the canonical moment conditions are analogous to the moments you'd use in OLS.